# buildSessionFactory in Hibernate alternatives

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, sessionfactory, hibernate-4.x

I am following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2F1zCAf_NU&feature=relmfu) tutorial  on Hibernate. The tutorial is quite old already since it still uses the old buildSessionFactory().

My Question is how would I use the latest `buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)` I am new to hibernate. I have no idea how would I implement this. this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
    ud.setId(1);
    ud.setName("David Jone");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(ud);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}
```

Also it would really help if you guys could link a tutorial for Hibernate 4 without Maven.

Comment: I don't fancy using Hibernate without Maven (or an alternative dependency management tool). Sounds error prone and time consuming especially if you're learning.

Comment: @Alex so are you suggesting that I should use Hibernate with Maven while I am learning Hibernate?

Comment: I would certainly do that. It means that you won't have issues with mismatched/missing dependencies. It'll make the whole experience easier and is good practice for later. When you start on a bigger project you won't want to manually handle your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are new to Hibernate and struggling with its basics. I would suggest you to go through the documentation and learn the concept.

[Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html) is a good starting point to understands some basics.

Also I have written [series of articles on Hibernate](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/introduction-to-hibernate-framework-architecture/) which you might want to go through.

And for accessing SessionFactory programatically, I suggest you to use following Hibernate Utility class as given in this tutorial:

[Hibernate Hello World example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-maven-mysql-hello-world-example-xml-mapping/)

```
package net.viralpatel.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration()
                    .configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Once you have this class, you can use it like:

```
private static Employee save(Employee employee) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Long id = (Long) session.save(employee);
    employee.setId(id);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();

    return employee;
}
```

Hope this helps.